# Is it necessary for a uml state machine to have a shallow history?

Tags: uml, history

Our supervisor said it is necessary for a composite state to have a shallow history..otherwise your tool that you are building does not make sense? Is this correct?
The tool is an undergraduate project that allows a subset of class and state machine diagrams to be built..you can see screenshot on cyrusuml.com

Comment: Some context around `your tool that you are building` wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context, if the state machine needs to roll-back for any reason then the answer is yes.  A example would be Parser for an LALR ([Look-Ahead/Left to Right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser)) Grammar were it is essential.  However if there are is no need for roll-back then the answer would be no.

In this case since you are modeling state machines you need to be able to handle both kinds, those with and without roll-back; other wise as he says your tool is useless.